# My Bitcoin.com wallet is asking for a password to confirm send that was never established. So im screwed or file a class action for this?

Tags: wallet

[image]

Wtf is this. Password was never established so i cant send this or get it back. So who is the dummy(besides me) that creates something with no way to retrieve your funds? This is ridiculous

Answer (score 2):

If you really never set a PIN, and obvious things like "0000" don't work, then this might be a bug in the app software.  You could report the bug at https://github.com/bitcoin-com/wallet/issues, and include full details about what you did.  They might have suggestions about what to do, but there may or may not be a workaround.

I suggest that you avoid expressing anger, frustration, or legal threats in your bug report.  The developers probably want to fix the bug, and they would rather work with people who seem motivated and cooperative.  If you seem like a difficult person to work with, they won't want to, and you can't force or intimidate them into doing so.

You could try deleting or resetting the app and restoring it using the 12-word recovery phrase that you created when you first installed the wallet.  It should also be possible to use the recovery phrase to access your coins from different wallet software.

If you didn't save the recovery phrase, or you have lost it, then you may have just learned an expensive lesson about the importance of backups.  Software bugs are just one of the many things that can go wrong when using Bitcoin; you can also lose or break your device, get coins stolen by malware, etc, etc.  These are the risks you take, and backups are one of the prudent ways to reduce those risks.  (Actually setting a PIN is another.)

As to whether you can sue, you'd have to consult a lawyer who knows about consumer law in your jurisdiction.  Personally, I doubt that you would be successful.  It's likely that the app's terms of use were carefully written by Bitcoin.com's lawyers to shield them from legal liability in case of software bugs.  In general, when you use free software, you should assume that it's at your own risk, and that nobody will compensate you if things go wrong.

Comment: I do have the recovery phrase all 12 of them. Still can't seem to get it. CryptoDave is on the case.

Answer (score 0):

Don,t worry at all. That's what happened to me. All I had to do was deleting the app and reinstalling it again. After entering my user name and password (I had already logged in) I was allowed to set my pin. No further problems.